# Group by tuple in Pig

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

I've been stuck on this question for a while. I have a data file that looks like this:

```
(1,N,N,5,High,H,House,d)
(1,N,N,6,High,H,House,a)    
(2,N,N,10,Low,H,House,t)    
(2,N,N,11,Medium,H,House,e)
```

I wanted my output in the below format. Can I achieve it using Pig???

```
{1,(N,N),{(5,High),(H,House),d},{(6,High),(H,House),a}}

{2,(N,N),{(10,Low),(H,House),t}{(11,Medium),(H,House),e}}
```

I actually tried to group it by first column.

```
datafile = LOAD '/user/zbc/xyz.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (id:int, 
    flag1:chararray, flag2:chararray, typcode:chararray, typ_name:chararray, 
    groupcode:charray, groupname:chararray, date:chararray);

collected = FOREACH datafile Generate TOBAG(gst_id, TOTUPLE(flag1,flag2), 
TOBAG(TOTUPLE(typcode, typname), TOTUPLE(groupcode, groupname), date));
```

I'm not getting how to proceed further. To group by "one field and one tuple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you were in the right direction, but you are creating the bags yourself instead of letting Pig do it when grouping. After loading the data, simplify your second step only creating the tuple you want, the combination of both flags:

```
collected = FOREACH datafile Generate id, TOTUPLE(flag1, flag2), $3..;
```

The `$3..` tells Pig to include from the fourth (it starts at `$0`) onwards, so you don't have to repeat the whole list of parameters. Now you will have this:

```
(1,(N,N),5,High,H,House,d)
(1,(N,N),6,High,H,House,a)
(2,(N,N),10,Low,H,House,t)
(2,(N,N),11,Medium,H,House,e)
```

Now, you can use the `group by` operator to group by any combination of fields you want, which in this case is by the `id` and the flags tuple:

```
desired_output = group collected by (id, $1);
```

After this, you get the data grouped as you wanted:

```
((1,(N,N)),{(1,(N,N),6,High,H,House,a),(1,(N,N),5,High,H,House,d)})
((2,(N,N)),{(2,(N,N),11,Medium,H,House,e),(2,(N,N),10,Low,H,House,t)})
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want the fields you grouped by to appear in the final bag, you can take them out using a nested foreach:

```
filtered_output = foreach desired_output {
    AUX = foreach collected generate $2..;
    generate group, AUX;
}
```

Output:

```
((1,(N,N)),{(6,High,H,House,a),(5,High,H,House,d)})
((2,(N,N)),{(11,Medium,H,House,e),(10,Low,H,House,t)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here in this case the group by fields are getting repeated for each record i.e., (1,(N,N)). But I wanted it to appear only once. Exactly like this {1,(N,N),{(5,High),(H,House),d},{(6,High),(H,House),a}}...... can I achieve that?

Comment: That is [how the group by works](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#group). For each group, you get a row with two fields: a tuple containing the group values (the `id` and the `flags`), the a bag with each of the *original* rows from that group. The original rows contain those values, so you get them once again.

Comment: @ShilpaGowda check my edit to avoid those duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks a ton.... This output almost looks similar to the desired output.... But if u observe my desired output i.e, {1,(N,N),{(5,High),(H,House),d},{(6,High),(H,House),a}}.... I wanted to created a single bag containing 2 bags inside it .... the 2 bags are {(5,High),(H,House),d} derived from 1st record and {(6,High),(H,House),a} derived from 2nd record....... Both combined together should constitute one bag which is grouped with id and a tuple...... Can I achieve that??? 
And on top of this I even want to name my bags and tuples

Comment: Probably a little late but you could swap `generate group, AUX;` for `generate group.id as id, group.b as b, AUX;`. Note I made up the field `b` since in the above the stuff in the 2nd position is not named. Use whatever names exist in your data in place of `b`.