# How to transfrom a few columns of a dataframe to a tuple

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
+---+----+------+-------+------+
| Id|fomrid|values|occ| comments
+---+----+------+-------+------+
|  1| x1  |   22.0|   1|  text1|
|  1| x1  |   test|   2| text2 |
|  1| x1  |     11|   3| text3 |
|  1| x2  |    21 |  0 | text4 |
|  2| p1  |     1 |   1| text5 |
+---+----+------+-------+------+
```

The transformed dataframe should look this

```
+---+------+--------------+--------+------+
| Id|fomrid|tuple(values) |tuple(occ)| comments
+---+------+--------------+--------+------+
|  1| x1   |(22.0, test,11)| ([1,2,3)|  text1|
|  1| x2   | (21)          | (0)     | text4 |
|  2| p1   | (1)           | (1)     | text5 |
+---+-----+---------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, it should be noted that spark does not have a data/column type for tuple with the closest representation being that of a list.

However, if you would like your data represented as a tuple string you may may use [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) to group your items before casting it to a string and replacing the square brackets with curved braces to achieve this.

#### Using spark sql

Creating a temporary view and running this on your spark session

```
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_temp_table_or_view")
output_df = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    fomrid,
    CONCAT('(',REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(collect_list(values) AS STRING),'[\\\[\\\]]',''),')') as tuple_values,
    CONCAT('(',REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(collect_list(occ) AS STRING),'[\\\[\\\]]',''),')') as tuple_occ,
    MIN(comments) as comments
FROM
   my_temp_table_or_view
GROUP BY
   Id, fomrid
```

**Outputs**

```
+---+------+----------------+---------+--------+
| Id|fomrid|    tuple_values|tuple_occ|comments|
+---+------+----------------+---------+--------+
|  1|    x1|(22.0, test, 11)|(1, 2, 3)|   text1|
|  1|    x2|            (21)|      (0)|   text4|
|  2|    p1|             (1)|      (1)|   text5|
+---+------+----------------+---------+--------+
```

#### Using pyspark api

```py
output_df = (
    input_df.groupBy(["Id","fomrid"])
            .agg(
                F.concat(
                    F.lit('('),
                    F.regexp_replace(
                        F.collect_list("values").cast("STRING"),
                        '[\\[\\]]',
                        ''
                    ),
                    F.lit(')')
                ).alias("tuple_values"),
                F.concat(
                    F.lit('('),
                    F.regexp_replace(
                        F.collect_list("occ").cast("STRING"),
                        '[\\[\\]]',
                        ''
                    ),
                    F.lit(')')
                ).alias("tuple_occ"),
                F.min("comments").alias("comments")               
            )
)
```

#### Using scala spark api

```
val output_df = 
    input_df.groupBy("Id","fomrid")
            .agg(
                concat(
                    lit("("),
                    regexp_replace(
                        collect_list("values").cast("STRING"),
                        "[\\[\\]]",
                        ""
                    ),
                    lit(")")
                ).alias("tuple_values"),
                concat(
                    lit("("),
                    regexp_replace(
                        collect_list("occ").cast("STRING"),
                        "[\\[\\]]",
                        ""
                    ),
                    lit(")")
                ).alias("tuple_occ"),
                min("comments").alias("comments")               
            )
```

### Edit 1:

At the time of writing, as it pertains to desiring a tuple column type for your pig script, Spark nor parquet, does not support a tuple type natively. Pig uses special writers/readers to convert parquet fields when using this type.

It may be more ideal to try modifying or using an intermediary pig script to

1. read, transform and store this in the desired type as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047008/4307136) or
2. converting a string to a tuple as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338341/how-to-convert-string-to-tuple-in-pig) ?
3. You could also try saving as a struct type and seeing if that works for you.  I've included a snippet, written in pyspark that dynamically determines and creates a struct type for these fields `List_values` and `List_occ`. Although I have tested this code on my spark setup, I do not have a pig setup at this time. Please update me whether either of these approaches including the links above work for you.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    input_df.groupBy("Id","fomrid")
            .agg(
                F.collect_list("values").alias("List_values"),
                F.collect_list("occ").alias("List_occ"),
                F.min("comments").alias("comments")               
            )
)
output_df.show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+------+----------------+---------+--------+
| Id|fomrid|     List_values| List_occ|comments|
+---+------+----------------+---------+--------+
|  1|    x1|[22.0, test, 11]|[1, 2, 3]|   text1|
|  1|    x2|            [21]|      [0]|   text4|
|  2|    p1|             [1]|      [1]|   text5|
+---+------+----------------+---------+--------+
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# determine max number of fields to include in struct based on max size of each field
max_field_sizes = output_df.selectExpr(
    "MAX(size(List_values)) as max_list_values",
    "MAX(size(List_occ)) as max_list_occ"
).first().asDict()

# dynamically create schemas with nullable fields to support these fields
list_value_schema = T.StructType([ T.StructField(str(i),T.StringType(),True) for i in range(0,max_field_sizes['max_list_values'])])
occ_value_schema = T.StructType([ T.StructField(str(i),T.StringType(),True) for i in range(0,max_field_sizes['max_list_occ'])])

# use udf to complete transformation from list to custom schema
@F.udf(returnType=list_value_schema)
def udf_transform_list_values_to_struct(list_values,max_field_size):
    return_value = {}
    for idx,val in enumerate(list_values):
        return_value[str(idx)]=val
    return return_value

@F.udf(returnType=occ_value_schema)
def udf_transform_list_occ_to_struct(list_values,max_field_size):
    return_value = {}
    for idx,val in enumerate(list_values):
        return_value[str(idx)]=val
    return return_value

# perform transformations using udfs
updated_output_df = output_df.withColumn('List_values',
                                 udf_transform_list_values_to_struct(
                                     F.col('List_values'),
                                     F.lit(max_field_sizes['max_list_values'])
                                 )
                                )

updated_output_df = updated_output_df.withColumn('List_occ',
                                 udf_transform_list_occ_to_struct(
                                     F.col('List_occ'),
                                     F.lit(max_field_sizes['max_list_occ'])
                                 )
                                )
# verification only. Printing schema and showing results
updated_output_df.printSchema()
updated_output_df.show()
```

**Output**

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fomrid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- List_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- List_occ: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- comments: string (nullable = true)

+---+------+----------------+---------------+--------+
| Id|fomrid|     List_values|       List_occ|comments|
+---+------+----------------+---------------+--------+
|  1|    x1|{22.0, test, 11}|      {1, 2, 3}|   text1|
|  1|    x2|{21, null, null}|{0, null, null}|   text4|
|  2|    p1| {1, null, null}|{1, null, null}|   text5|
+---+------+----------------+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Code is working fine. But datatype of the tuple is a string, datatype should be a tuple. 
We are writing this dataframe to a parquet file which is consumed by a PIG script and these fields (values, occ) are defined as a tuple (field_values:tuple()) in PIG script.

Comment: @amamagar I was not aware that the intended recipient of this data was apache pig. I have included an edit my answer, let me know if either propoal works for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Let me give you some more background.
We are transforming a set of JSON files to a sequential file using Map/Reduce code and then using PIG script which consumes this sequential file for further transformation. 
Here is the snippet of the pig script
--

Comment: %DECLARE SEQFILE_LOADER 'com.wk.axcess.iq.dataplane.seqfilereader.pig.udf.TestFileLoader';

DEFINE LOAD_TAX_DATA(path) returns r {
    r1 = LOAD '$path' USING $SEQFILE_LOADER() AS (id:chararray, clientguid:chararray, formId:chararray, field_values:tuple(), comments:chararray);
    r2 = FOREACH r1 GENERATE field_id, TOTUPLE(id, field_values, clientguid, comments) AS field_attributes;
    r3 = GROUP r2 BY (field_attributes.id, field_attributes.clientGuid, field_attributes.comments);
    $r = FOREACH r3 { field_map = TOMAP(r2); GENERATE group AS return, field_map AS field_map; }
};

Comment: TestFileLoader is a udf which uses org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory to generate tuple:
Tuple valueTuple = tupleFactory.newTupleNoCopy(valueList);
  return TupleFactory.getInstance()
    .newTuple(Arrays.asList(fieldId, w.id, w.formId, valueTuple, w.clientGuid, w.comments))

---
Our plan is to replace Map/reduce with Databricks but make it work with existing pig scripts (with minimal changes).
With you help, I'm able to convert JSON files to dataframes but struggling to generate tuples.

I hope this helps.

Thanks for the help.